# Javascript: replace tagged template literals in string

Tags: javascript

I have this string which consist of the following :

```
const string = `describe('Test', () => {
  it('found', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(`${prefix}/test`)
  });
  it('array', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(`${prefix}/test`)
  });
});`
```

When i try to console log this string, i get that `${prefix}` is an `Unexpected identifier`, when i try to replace it with something else, i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenation between different part of string:

```
const string = `describe('Test', () => {
  it('found', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(`+`${prefix}/test`+`)
  });
  it('array', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(`+`${prefix}/test`+`)
  });
});`
```

Comment: i need to since in my original file /test is a string and not a retreived value

Comment: @brxnzaz OK check it now

Comment: I can't just change my string since i retreive it from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need backtick inside the string.

```
const string = `describe('Test', () => {
  it('found', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(${prefix}/test)
  });
  it('array', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get(${prefix}/test)
  });
});`
```

Comment: i can't since i retreive that string from a file like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add quote marks:

```
const string = `describe('Test', () => {
  it('found', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get('${prefix}/test')
  });
  it('array', async () => {
    await createUser();
    const test = await agent.get('${prefix}/test')
  });
});`
```

Comment: i can't add it since i retreive that string from a file like that.